# sikuli java, second click() problems and so on

Tags: java, sikuli

my code is extremely simple... 
I use

```
public static String play = "C:\\pics\\lotto\\play.png";
public static String playmenu = "C:\\pics\\lotto\\playmenu.png";

s.click(play);
robot.delay(1000);
s.click(playmenu);
r.delay(1000);
```

it is a repeat process

It always clicks the first image, but never the second image. If i flip it, it clicks the first image still, as it recognizes both images, but never clicks the second image.

What i mean by click is, it does not move the mouse to the second image and click. hover does not work, mouseMove doesnt work, hover and mouseClick no work .

It is as if windows is blocking any mousemovements after the first command.

I have put print screen, it goes through all commands, does every code i enter, except mouse move/click with robot or sikuli

Any help on this? is it a windows setting or something else? 
Been reasearching 2 weeks on this, didnt want to bug ppl with questions but im completely stuck

much appreciated for any help. ty

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using netbeans with java, and the sikulixapi

Answer (score 0):

2 things may happen with this:

```
public static String play = "C:\\pics\\lotto\\play.png";
public static String playmenu = "C:\\pics\\lotto\\playmenu.png";

s.click(play);
robot.delay(1000);
s.click(playmenu);
r.delay(1000);
```

One of the things it could be happening is that when you click play.png, the screen changes, so you can't find playmenu.png. You should ask yourself if:

- playmenu.png depends on play.png? Maybe, when you click over play, playmenu changes the color, size, borders and you can't find it.
- What is the pattern coincidence of both images? Maybe they need to be lower than the average. One thing I would do is to check if both of them exists, first (Like this):

  ```
  // You can change the pattern of coincidence (need 85% of coincidence to be recognized)
  if (s.exists(new Pattern(play).similar(0.85f)) != null) {
      System.out.println("Play exists!");
  }
  if (s.exists(new Pattern(playmenu).similar(0.85f)) != null) {
      System.out.println("Playmenu exists!");
  }
  ```

This previous lines are only to check if those images exists. Now, if you notice that after you click the first image the second image is not being clicked, you can do something like this:

```
    s.click(new Pattern(play).similar(0.8f));
    robot.delay(1000);
    /* Another thing you can do is, after you click the first image (play), 
    you can move the mouse to another coordinate to lost animations after
    focus the first button, and recover the original aspect*/
    r.mouseMove(0,0);
    // Here, you lower the level of coincidence so it match with the new image
    s.click(new Pattern(playmenu).similar(0.6f));
    r.delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've learned with Sikuli is to make sure you capture the smallest unique image possible. Try not to make the image capture larger than needed to be unique on the screen (unique, meaning that it can't be discovered in multiple places). Be careful not to capture any background if it's not necessary. Also, resolution consistency between writing environment and running environment is crucial for reliable tests results. Sikuli can be quite frustrating at first, however it forces the test writer to examine in-depth how a user will interact with the application. The process of writing Sikuli tests in itself, in my opinion, is a beneficial tool for manual testing.